# Correct way to check text of button?

Tags: android, android-espresso

Correct way to check text of button

I  need to check that English text on button is "**Start this**".

In **string.xml**

```
<string name="start">Start this</string>
```

So here Espresso test:

**Approach#1**

```
private val buttonStart = viewWithId(startButton)

    @Test
    fun buttonStartText() {
        onView(withId(startButton))
                .check(matches(withText(R.string.start)))
}
```

The test "`buttonStartText`"  success pass. Nice.

**Approach#2**

Check hard code text.

```
 @Test
    fun buttonStartText() {
        onView(withId(startButton))
                .check(matches(withText("Start this")))
}
```

The test "`buttonStartText`"  success pass. Nice.

The question is: 
What approach is correct?

What I mean.
Suppose the developer made error and in `string.xml` change value of key "**start**" to `"Start this 2222"`.
E.g.

```
<string name="start">Start this 2222</string>
```

As result the test in **approach#1** is still pass. This is **NOT CORRECT** behavior.

But test in `approach#2` is broken. This is a correct behavior.

As result I think test in `approach#2` is correct way to check title/text on button.

Is I'm right?

**P.S.**

But if I has multi language app (e.g. 3 languages). In **approach#1** nothing cha nge. But in in **approach#2** I need to add two additional tests that check text in specific languages.

Comment: I don't like approach 1 because if you made a typo in your strings.xml, then the expected output will succeed despite it being wrong.

Comment: But if I has multi language app (e.g. 3 languages). Then in approach#2 I need to add two additional tests that check text in specific languages.

Comment: But approach #1 with button.setText(R.string.start) not checking anything other than just there is a the same resource with unknown text. 
So if someone will change resource string test will still pass even if text on button will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think approach #1 is correct as you cover all the local's in that else in approach #2 you only cover english or specific language.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest both approach are correct.

Because approach #1 checking if there is a button with text from R.strings..

but approach #2 checking if there is exactly that text.

So You are checking two different things. Depends what You want to test.

Comment: But if I has multi language app (e.g. 3 languages). Then in approach#2 I need to add two additional tests that check text in specific languages.

Comment: But approach #1 with button.setText(R.string.start) not checking anything other than just there is a the same resource with unknown text. 
So if someone will change resource string test will still pass even if text on button will be wrong.

Comment: So You can mix both approach to be sure. If there is a correct resource string and if there is a correct text for example in English.